FastAPI - Pydantic model does not allow space in value of string Enum value?
python 3.12.5
pydantic 2.8.2 
fastapi 0.111.1 

Running in a docker container on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Here is the model class definition:
from enum import Enum
from app.models.common.base import DomainModel
    
class ProjectState(str, Enum):
    ACTIVE = "active"
    ARCHIVED = "archived"
    
class ProjectType(str, Enum):
    MIGRATION_CONFIG = "Migration Config"
    MIGRATION_CLEANUP = "Migration_Cleanup"
    
class Project(DomainModel):
    name: str
    type: ProjectType.MIGRATION_CONFIG
    customer_id: str
    state: ProjectState = ProjectState.ACTIVE

The value for enum ProjectType.MIGRATION_CONFIG has a space character in it. This space character prevents fastapi server from starting because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Forward reference must be an expression -- got <ProjectType.MIGRATION_CONFIG: 'Migration Config'>

If I change the space character to underscore character, then fastapi server has no problem to startup.
I don't quite understand the message in the SyntaxError. It doesn't seem to be problem in python without pydantic.

Shouldn't type be type: ProjectType, and not the enum value? You're now using a string to define the type, you're not setting the default value (and type names must be valid Python identifiers - thus, they can't contain a space). Did you mean type: ProjectType = ProjectType.MIGRATION_CONFIG?

@MatsLindh You are absolutely correct! Thanks.

@MatsLindh: Is this a duplicate question?  If not, please add your answer as I'm sure others will make this same mistake.

@EthanFurman My close suggestion is that it's a typo, but I can see that it can be a common issue. I'm not aware of a previous answer, but haven't done any attempts at searching either I've added my comment as a slightly more extensive answer now, but feel free to close as duplicate if someone finds the same issue in relation to Pydantic.

In your definition of Project you've given the enum value as the type, and not the enum itself.
class Project(DomainModel):
    name: str
    type: ProjectType.MIGRATION_CONFIG
          ^^^^^

Compare this to the property that's working as expected:
    state: ProjectState = ProjectState.ACTIVE

So, to correct it - use the enum as the type and the enum value as the default value:
class ProjectType(str, Enum):
    MIGRATION_CONFIG = "Migration Config"
    MIGRATION_CLEANUP = "Migration_Cleanup"
    
class Project(DomainModel):
    name: str
    type: ProjectType = ProjectType.MIGRATION_CONFIG

